# actionscript 3 file reference response data after uploading a file

Tags: actionscript-3, httpresponse

I have written a ac3 script to upload files to remote servers and it is working as expected with all the events.

From the server side script i am echoing some text according to the upload status and i want that status to be received in flash like response text in ajax.

Is it possible to receive response text from a server script after uploading a file.

Or it doesn't have to be a file upload yet i wanted to have the string echoed in the server side script as response text in flash.

If that is not possible like ajax or normal request and response then is there another ways of achieving that?

Here is the code which gets executed when upload is complete.

```
fr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event): void
{
    lblPer.text = 'Completed';
//  ExternalInterface.call("uploadError",e.target.data);

})
```

where fr is FileReference object.

Answer (score 1):

Try listening for `DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA`. That should have a `data` property on it that you can read the response from.

Comment: Sadly, it's triggered only when a data has been returned to it as a response.

Comment: @inhan Please clarify what do you mean. Responses usually have data.